# Is it safe to delete an entire Cassandra partition in a single DeleteQuery?

Tags: cassandra, nosql

I would like to know if it is safe to delete an entire partition in cassandra in a single DeleteQuery. How is the performance in this case ? Any insights ?

Answer (score 2):

Partition deletes is the best that you can do from performance standpoint because it generates only a single tombstone of special type.  You can read more about different types of deletes & tombstones in the following [great blog post](https://thelastpickle.com/blog/2016/07/27/about-deletes-and-tombstones.html).

Answer (score 2):

It is a matter of necessity, not a question of whether it is safe or not.

If you need to delete a partition then delete the partition. If you need to delete a row then delete the row. If you need to delete a column, delete the column.

I'm guessing that you've read somewhere that tombstones are an issue in Cassandra. The problem with tombstones isn't with the tombstones themselves -- it's whether you are [using Cassandra to process queues or queue-like datasets](http://www.datastax.com/dev/blog/cassandra-anti-patterns-queues-and-queue-like-datasets).

As a friendly note, a better question is "What problem are you trying to solve?" instead of asking an open-ended question without providing background information or context. Cheers!